# Can you play your apple id account from your PC. Clash of CLans

Tags: clash-of-clans

Lost my Iphone and want to know can I use my apple  id account online or on PC to  play clash of clans?

Comment: That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Apple ID -> Apple Software.

Answer (score 0):

You could borrow an iOS device and load your backup.

From there, you could follow the steps to migrate your villages to android so that you could load emulation software on your PC to play the android version of the game.

- [problem in transferring clash of clans village from an android to an ios device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143235/problem-in-transferring-clash-of-clans-village-from-an-android-to-an-ios-device)
- [How can I transfer or link my Clash of Clans account to an Android device, from iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200106/how-can-i-transfer-or-link-my-clash-of-clans-account-to-an-android-device-from)