# How can I transfer or link my Clash of Clans account to an Android device, from iOS?

Tags: iphone, game-center, clash-of-clans

How do I retrieve my Game Center username and password from my iPhone to my Android, so I can restore the progress of my Clash of Clans app?

Comment: By Game Center do you mean, Microsoft Game Center? If so, just go to the site and hit forgot your password and choose a method to reset it. If you use hotmail or yahoo, it is that emails password and the email address is your logon. If you are referring to the AppStore (since you are switching from iPhone to Android) the App Store is for iPhones (or other Mac products), and you will need to use either Google Play or the Microsoft Game Center since it cannot be used on your new Android.

Comment: @gracey209 Why wouldn't it be possible to transfer from iOS to Android?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your Game Center user and password —which in any case is usually your Apple ID and password; you can link devices in-game.

From the Supercell support site, specifically "[Transferring your game to another device](http://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&l=en&s=lost-village&f=transferring-your-game-to-another-device)":

> iOS > Android or Vice Versa
>
> First, make sure the game is installed on both devices, keeping them both on-hand. Use the “Link a device” feature in the in-game settings, and then select “Link a device” on both. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

The username and password are not stored in plain text.

I would open a support case with the vendor and link to the article they send you if you need help implementing a specific step in the process (since you might not even need to know the password to resume your clan).

Here's what you can do on the iPhone

- You can see your Game Center user name in the settings app
- You can reset the password if you truly lost it at https://appleid.apple.com or https://iforgot.apple.com - try the first through before resetting is my advice.